# Why is req.body undefined in my show & edit routes but not my create route?

Tags: javascript, express, body-parser

I refactored my code and broke some things out into models to simplify my app.js file. And once I did that, I started getting errors that items inside the req.body object are undefined. I can't, for the life of me, figure out why.

I've tried Googling the solution, searching on Stackoverflow, and reading my code about 5,000 times to find the problem, but to no avail.

```
var express             = require('express'),
    app                 = express(), 
    bodyParser          = require('body-parser'),
    methodOverride      = require('method-override'),
    expressSanitizer    = require("express-sanitizer"),
    mongoose            = require('mongoose'),
    Job                 = require("./models/job"),
    Worker              = require("./models/worker"),
    Boss                = require("./models/boss");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/tiny_gig", { useNewUrlParser: true });
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(expressSanitizer());
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));



// CREATE ROUTE
app.post("/jobs", function(req,res){
   req.body.job.jobInfo = req.sanitize(req.body.job.jobInfo); // <--- This works just fine.
   // Create job
   Job.create(req.body.job, function(err, newlyCreated){
        if(err){
          res.render("new");
        } else {
          res.redirect("/jobs");
        }       
   });
});


// SHOW ROUTE
app.get("/jobs/:id", function(req, res) {
   // Find the job with the specific ID
   console.log(req.body);
   Job.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundJob){
      if(err){
        res.redirect("/jobs");
      } else {
        res.render("show", {job: foundJob});
      }
   });
});


// EDIT ROUTE
app.get("/jobs/:id/edit", function(req, res) {
    req.body.job.jobInfo = req.sanitize(req.body.job.jobInfo); // <--- If I comment this line out, everything works...
    Job.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundJob){
        if(err){
            res.redirect("/jobs");
        } else {
            res.render("edit", {job: foundJob});
        }
    });
});
```

Here are the EJS templates:

```
// EDIT TEMPLATE
<% include partials/header %>
<div class="ui main text container segment">
    <div class="ui huge header">Edit "<%= job.title %>" </div>
    <form class="ui form" action="/jobs/<%= job._id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST"> 
        <div class="field">
            <input type="text" name="job[title]" value="<%= job.title %>">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <input type="text" name="job[preview]" value="<%= job.preview %>">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <textarea required name="job[jobInfo]"><%= job.jobInfo %></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <input class="ui teal basic button" type="submit">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

```
// SHOW TEMPLATE
<% include partials/header %>

<div class="ui main text container ">
    <div class="ui huge header"><%= job.title %></div>

    <div class="ui top attached segment">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="description">
                <p><%=job.jobInfo%></p>
                <div class="content">
                    <span><small>Created on:  <em><%= job.created.toDateString() %></em></small></span>
                </div>
                <a class="ui teal basic button" href="/jobs/<%= job._id %>/edit">Edit</a>
                <form id="delete" action="/jobs/<%= job._id %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                    <button class="ui red basic button">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
\\ JOBS MODEL
`code`
var mongoose = require("mongoose");


// JOB SCHEMA SETUP
var jobSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String, 
    preview: String,
    jobInfo: String,
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Job", jobSchema);
```

ERROR I'm getting

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'jobInfo' of undefined
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/TinyGig/TinyGig v2.semanticUI/app.js:71:53
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/TinyGig/TinyGig v2.semanticUI/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/ubuntu/workspace/TinyGig/TinyGig v2.semanticUI/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/ubuntu/workspace/TinyGig/TinyGig v2.semanticUI/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/TinyGig/TinyGig v2.semanticUI/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/TinyGig/TinyGig v2.semanticUI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at param (/home/ubuntu/workspace/TinyGig/TinyGig v2.semanticUI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:354:14)
    at param (/home/ubuntu/workspace/TinyGig/TinyGig v2.semanticUI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
    at Function.process_params (/home/ubuntu/workspace/TinyGig/TinyGig v2.semanticUI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:410:3)
    at next (/home/ubuntu/workspace/TinyGig/TinyGig v2.semanticUI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at methodOverride (/home/ubuntu/workspace/TinyGig/TinyGig v2.semanticUI/node_modules/method-override/index.js:65:14)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/TinyGig/TinyGig v2.semanticUI/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/ubuntu/workspace/TinyGig/TinyGig v2.semanticUI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/TinyGig/TinyGig v2.semanticUI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/ubuntu/workspace/TinyGig/TinyGig v2.semanticUI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/ubuntu/workspace/TinyGig/TinyGig v2.semanticUI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

Comment: Can you post the actual error you’re getting?

Comment: Sure thing. It's at the bottom of all the code above. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Side note - `GET /jobs/:id/edit` is not RESTful. An edit should either be a `PUT` or a `PATCH`

Comment: Missed my edit timer. Should be `PUT/PATCH /jobs/:id`

Comment: My EDIT route takes me to the form with the post pre-populated with the content the user filled out. The UPDATE route has the PUT verb. I'm still learning, but that's what I was taught regarding restful routing. I didn't post all my routes for brevity's sake, but I can if that's helpful?

Comment: I think I figured it out, though. req.body... was placed within the GET request. As per Sudhir's comment below, it should have been in the PUT request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

req.body is available only for post request not get request

your view and edit urls are registered as get request. You can use req.query to access url parameters

```
app.get("/jobs/:id", function(req, res) {

app.get("/jobs/:id/edit", function(req, res) {
```

Above lines needs to be modified

Use app.post() or change req.body to req.query to access URL parameters.

Comment: I'm not trying to access the url parameters, though. I'm simply trying to sanitize the information that's submitted in the create and edit forms for their respective routes.

Comment: I looked at my code again, and I didn't have the sanitize code in my PUT route. That explains my problem. Thanks for your help.